# Android: My emulator is not showing up in DDMS devices list

Tags: android-emulator, eclipse-plugin, ddms

Sometimes suddenly I'm unable to connect to `Emulator` from my `eclipse`, same time I'm not seeing the emultor under devices in `DDMS` perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `adb` causes your problem. I've created `adb restart.bat` (I use windows) file for such cases:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: @VenkatPapana In such cases restarting of emulator is needed